# Copy pin feature in email template

Tags: javascript, html-email, copy-paste

I have an email template with an 4 digit numeric pin. I need to implement a copy pin feature in the email template. Users should copy the pin by clicking on 'copy pin' text or copy icon in the email rather than selecting the texting and copying it manually.

It seems its not possible to do this because of the restrictrion of JS in email templates. But you never know, may be there is a workaround.

Comment: Short answer: It is not possible.    
Long answer: The email clients allow a restricted range of html elements and no JS whatsoever; this due to security reasons. There are some clients that allow some specific JS features but the behaviour is not consistent between clients.  The best thing you can do is to talk with your Marketing people and tell them that instead of making this feature in the email, they should instead allow the users to copy&paste that piece of text on the page where they are supposed paste it onto. THAT would be a welcomed feature from the user's perspective.

Comment: Might be easier to just put some text under the code asking users to copy paste. You can have the copy feature in the view online maybe.